# Handling many dynamically created TextView's

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataStrings.length; i++) {
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
    tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    tv1.setText(dataStrings[i]);
    dynamicLL.addView(tv1);
}
```

Basically, i am creating some amount of TextView's dynamically (the amount is unknown). I want each TextView to have its own `OnLongClickListener`. My question is how do I give each TextView its own unique OnLongClickListener when the TextViews are generated in this way, and how do I handle the clicks once the listener has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set them in your `for` loop, like this

```
OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener () {
    @Override 
    public void onLongClick (View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) ...
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < dataStrings.length; i++) {
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setId(i * 1000);
    tv1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
}
```

In your switch in a listener you can then check what `TextView` was pressed and do according action.

Comment: so something like "case 1000:" for the second listener for instance?

Comment: yes, you're right. you can provide any ids which are easy for you to use.

Comment: actually i just realised this method wont work. If I don't know how many TextView's will be created then how will I know how many case statements to use?

Comment: then how do you know how you want to handle the textview number of which is unknown?